# Add an FLV video on a jQuery tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I currently have a quick line going like this:

```
<img title="FLV Video goes here" class="tooltip" src="/images/icon-question.png" alt="questions" width="12" height="12" border="0" />
```

And when you hover over the image it shows the text in the title attribute, how would I go about embedding an swf in there? It contains javascript tags and div tags, putting it directly
into the title tag causes it to error out.

I am using the tooltip plugin for jquery.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hovertips instead: http://www.dave-cohen.com/node/1186.

This is what you need:

1. use jQuery and hovertip plug-in
2. call hovertipInit on $(document).ready
3. `<a id="a1">link</a>`
4. `<div class="hovertip" target="a1"><h1>jQuery rocks!</h1>I'm the newest member of the jQuery fan club!</div>`